# Disable all paging in git

Tags: git, emacs, terminal

I do all of my terminal work in emacs and would prefer to use the much richer tools for moving around the output than "less". Worse, any time an applications pages inside of emacs, it is horribly annoying because it is a dumb terminal.

While I can swap things like "git help rm" for "M-x man git-rm", I would prefer to just disable all paging of everything in git. Then I don't have to hunt for the right incantations.

```
  git config --global core.pager cat
```

Doesn't seem to do the trick.

```
  git config --global man.viewer "man -P cat"
```

causes problems because "man -P cat" isn't a valid executable.

How can I get git to just dump its output?

Comment: `git -c core.pager=cat log` works just fine for me.

Comment: I really wish I could mark two answers as correct, because there are two things you need to do to really accomplish this. The first is turning off core.pager (see kan's answer). The second is turning of man paging (see geoff's answer). I marked Geoff's as the correct answer because I had already figured out the first but couldn't get the second firgured out.

Comment: I added `(setenv "PAGER" "cat")` to my Emacs init file and everything just worked.  No git specific setting required.  This has the added benefit that in a regular shell git works with its usual pager.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From reading the `git help` manpage it looks like you should be able to

```
git config --global man.viewer catman
git config --global man.catman.cmd "man -P cat"
```

The `man.viewer` config value is a tool name, not a (partial) command line. Then `man.catman.cmd` gives the command to use for the `catman` tool.

It seems like setting `core.pager` to `cat` should take care of everything else.

Comment: This is the one I was missing. Thanks for figuring out the additional step I needed to make it work!

Answer (score 15):

> To disable pagination for all commands, set `core.pager` or
>   `GIT_PAGER` to `cat`.

(c) http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html

Addition. You also asked about `git help`. It actually not a git's pager, it is `$MANPAGER`. So maybe for you it will be enough just make `PAGER=cat`.

`PAGER=cat git help log` works with no pagers.

Comment: As I mentioned in the original question, this didn't solve all of the problems. It is certainly a solution to part of the "problem", so an upvote is in order.

Comment: It works fine too if you set `GIT_PAGER` to an empty string: `GIT_PAGER= git log` (at least since git 1.8.x).

Answer (score 5):

Adding to [Geoff Reedy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12166903/2745495), this also gets rid of the `_` and `^H` in the man pages:

```
git config --global core.pager cat
git config --global man.viewer catman
git config --global man.catman.cmd 'man -P "col -b"'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try `alias git='git --no-pager'`. Or if that doesn't work for some reason inside of emacs, you could create a `git` shell script somewhere earlier in your `PATH` that calls the real `git --no-pager`.

Comment: This was my first shot at it and it solved some of the problems, but not all of them. This is roughly equivalent to setting core.pager to cat above.

Comment: this was the only solution that did what I wanted, faster commands

Answer (score 1):

`git config --global core.pager ""`

works for me