# Why is "git grep" behaving erratic on my Windows PC?

Tags: windows, git, github, grep, git-bash

I'm using Github and `Git bash` on my Windows PC (running `XP`).

On Ubuuntu I'm happyily using `git grep` to plough through my code, but every time I call something like:

```
git grep "some text in my repo"
```

on Windows I get the results and afterwards I'm stuck with the bash window showing all kind of things `[END], ~, [RETURN]...` whenever I try to enter something.

**Question:**
What else besides `CTRL+R, CTRL+Q, FN+END, Q, ESC` can I try to not having to force-close and reopen git:bash in order to continue to work.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
This is what I mean:

[image]

As soon as I start typing, the [END] string re-appears (or 50 lines `~`) and I cannot write any command on Git, because whatever is in the way swallows half of what I'm typing.... nice description...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was wondering about this also after installing git and running git bash.  It seems "git grep" pipes commands through "less".

Solution: Just type <kbd>q</kbd>.

Comment: yeah. or close the window :-)

Answer (score 1):

Is git launching less (or something similar) so up/down arrows on your keyboard scrolls through the matches? If you don't want that, try the instructions from https://stackoverflow.com/a/12166923/972216:

```
set GIT_PAGER=cat
```

Would disable it for your console session once, or

```
git config --global core.pager cat
```

to disable it for your account.

Comment: Nope. I would say, this makes it even worse :-D

Comment: Oh really? Huh, well then I have no idea. :-)

Comment: Ok. Still thanks. Maybe this helps: How do I exit the "grep view",  so that I can resume normal "git-operations"?