# Turning off the pager in git by default

Tags: git, pager

[Turning off the pager in git for the stash command only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225350/turning-off-the-pager-in-git-for-the-stash-command-only) and [Disable all paging in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166295/disable-all-paging-in-git) doesn't answer to this question because I sometimes want use the pager, but not by default, I just want git use pager when I add -p option

Update 2021-02-11 , one partial solution, I think that can do in some pieces, for example for branch command:

```
git config --global pager.branch false
```

Update 2022-06-15 for me the best solution but -p will not work:

```
git config --global core.pager ""
```

2022-06-15 : as I use a terminal with scroll bar , seems for me that will be more productive limit the entries of output than put in pager , for me instead write in terminal (I use konsole) for here I can copy, paste and search . If output goes to a pager the output will be lost forever when we leave the pager

Now just need to find out, how I limit the results to 100 or 200

I mean `git log` by default be `git log -100`

in conclusion Git doesn't offer an option to do this , so this question falls in [Disable all paging in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166295/disable-all-paging-in-git)

Comment: Running "git config --global core.pager off" will configure git to use a program named "off" as the pager.  That is not normally what you want.

Comment: Instead, set the pager to the empty string to disable it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git doesn't offer an option to do this, so you have a couple of options:

- Set `core.pager` to `cat` and then create an alias that you use that calls `git -c core.pager=less` (or whatever you want).
- Make `git` a shell function in your shell that does something like this:

```
git () {
    local pager=""
    
    for arg in "$@"
    do
        [ "$arg" = "-p" ] && pager="-c core.pager=less"
    done

    command git $pager "$@"
}
```

Comment: I have `core.pager` set to `cat`, but I haven't bothered defining an alias. I just do `git blah blah | less`, as I do with any other command.

Comment: `core.pager` set to `cat`  was enough for me too.